# Detecting Multitouch on rectangle in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have two rectangle A and B.What I have to do is, When my first rectangle(A) is pressed, my second rectangle(B) would not be click able for 3 seconds and vice-versa. Also, If any of the rectangle is pressed, then another is click able only when, the user touchUp the Screen.
i.e. both rectangles should not be click able with a single touch.

I am doing as follows:

```
boolean leftleftRectBool = false,rightRectBool = false;
long scanningTime =  System.currentTimeMillis()+3000;//in constructor

camera.unproject(touchPoint.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
    if(Gdx.input.isTouched())
    {
        if (leftThumbRectangle.contains(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
                    if (scanningTime > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                leftRectBool = false;
                scanningTimeStart = true;
            } else {
                scanningTime = 0;
                scanningTimeStart = false;
                leftRectBool = true;
                   }

             }
if(rightThumbRectangle.contains(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
                       if (scanningTime > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                rightRectBool = false;
                scanningTimeStart = true;
            } else {
                scanningTime = 0;
                scanningTimeStart = false;
                rightRectBool = true;
                   }
}

else {

        scanningTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 3000;
     }
           if(lefttRectBool && lefttRectBool)
             {
              // some thing happen
             }
```

and in draw()

```
if(lefttRectBool)
{
//some thing haapens
}
else if(rightRectBool)
{
//some things happen
}
```

Comment: Its not clear what you want here? What exactly do you want help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take two variables for scanning times i.e. for two rectangles.

```
    boolean leftleftRectBool = false,rightRectBool = false;
long scanningTimeRight =  System.currentTimeMillis()+3000;
long scanningTimeLeft =  System.currentTimeMillis()+3000;

camera.unproject(touchPoint.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
    if(Gdx.input.isTouched())
    {
        if (leftThumbRectangle.contains(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
                    if (scanningTime > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                leftRectBool = false;
                scanningTimeStart = true;
            } else {
                scanningTimeRight = System.currentTimeMillis()+3000;
                scanningTimeStart = false;
                leftRectBool = true;
                   }

             }
if(rightThumbRectangle.contains(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
                       if (scanningTime > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                rightRectBool = false;
                scanningTimeStart = true;
            } else {
                scanningTimeLeft = System.currentTimeMillis()+3000;
                scanningTimeStart = false;
                rightRectBool = true;
                   }
}

else {

        scanningTimeRight = System.currentTimeMillis() + 3000;
        scanningTimeLeft = System.currentTimeMillis()+3000;
     }
           if(lefttRectBool && lefttRectBool)
             {
              // some thing happen
             }
```

Try this. This may work.